# What is the easiest way to determine if a Model's current attributes are different than the defaults?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a model with the following defaults:

```
Entities.OrdersFilter = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'start-date': '2014-09-01',
        'end-date': '2014-10-01',
        'status': 'OUTSTANDING'
    },
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage('OrderFilters')
});
```

These three attributes represent filters that can be changed by the user. I need to display a "Clear Filters" button, but only when the filters differ from the defaults. I know Backbone supplies a `hasChanged` state, but I believe that will just tell me if it's changed since the last `set`, not from the defaults.

How do I check to see if a Model's current attribute values are different than the defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone already provides a [changedAttributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes) method that checks if the current attributes are different from the ones you provide in a hash (in your case, this hash will be the model default values).

From Backbone's **changedAttribute** documentation:

> Retrieve a hash of only the model's attributes that have changed since
>   the last set, or false if there are none. Optionally, an external
>   attributes hash can be passed in, returning the attributes in that
>   hash which differ from the model. This can be used to figure out which
>   portions of a view should be updated, or what calls need to be made to
>   sync the changes to the server.

So you could for example write something like:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'start-date': '2014-09-01',
        'end-date': '2014-10-01',
        'status': 'OUTSTANDING'
    },
    changedFromDefaults: function(){
        return this.changedAttributes(this.defaults) !== false; 
    }
});
```

And use it like this:

```
var model = new MyModel();
console.log(model.changedFromDefaults()); //false

model.set('status', "FOO");
console.log(model.changedFromDefaults()); //true

model.set('status', "OUTSTANDING");
console.log(model.changedFromDefaults()); //false
```

I have create [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v69snLpo/) so you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In you Backbone.View, you've to listen to your model changes :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.compareToDefaults);
  },
  compareToDefaults: function(model){
    // here, you can compare each model value with the default ones.
    // and display or not display your RESET button.
  }
});
```